# printing a big database with 20 fields in it

Tags: ms-access, database-design, printing

I'm facing some issue while printing database with 20 fields in it.
I am using MS Access Database. I want to print my datasheet such that, when End of page is reached (i.e., Left to Right) the remaining Columns should be printed in second line of the page.
e.g.

```
A B C D E F G |(end)

a b c d e f g |

H I J

h i j
```

Here Capital letters are Column name and letters in 2nd alphabet are the values.

Comment: Are you having problems setting up a report?

Comment: This is what reports are for.

Answer (score 1):

What you are going to want to do is create a Report for this. In which case, line wrapping just becomes an exercise in placing the fields and their Labels.

You can do this two ways:

1) You can put the field names in the Page or Report header section as Labels, and then put the fields in the Detail section.

2) You can put both the field names and the fields in the detail section. In which case, you will see field names for EVERY record that is printed out as part of the report.

Most people prefer to use the first option.